# Center align child absolute element with more than parent width

Tags: css

I have a Div and span inside it. I am using span as title element. So it should appear only on :hover. It works fine using :hover class.

But how can I make sure that the span element appears exactly in the middle of parent like in below image.

[image]

instead of

[image]

Please note that width of span element is not fixed.

[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/yunofebobu/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Both solution works (answers below) if your browser support is high (as in supporing a lot of older browsers) then use the non flex way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `left: 50%` to your demo [(here updated)](http://jsbin.com/cahaminiqa/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

```css
.hasToolTip {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
.title {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;          /* so text don't break line when have space char */
}
.hasToolTip:hover .title {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="hasToolTip">
  <span class="title">16753r2364</span>
</div>
<div class="hasToolTip">
  <span class="title">16753r2364and then some</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flex` and `justify-content: space-around` in your parent element:

```css
.hasToolTip {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  display: flex; /* add flex */
  justify-content: space-around; /* add this */
}
.title {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;  /* change to relative */
  top: -20px; /* decrease top a bit */
  left: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap; /* for scenarios with very long text with spaces */
}
.hasToolTip:hover .title {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="hasToolTip">
  <span class="title">16753r2364</span>
</div>
<div class="hasToolTip">
  <span class="title">16753asdasdasdasasdr2364</span>
</div>
<div class="hasToolTip">
  <span class="title">16753asdasdasdasasdr2364 asdasdasdasdasdasdadas</span>
</div>
```

**References**

[flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

[justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Comment: Thanks. Its super cool. But accepted below as I could not use your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your what you are after, hover over the bottom div:

```css
.hasToolTip {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: red;
position:relative;
}

.title {
   visibility: hidden;
   top: -30px;  
   text-align:center;
       position: absolute;
   transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.hasToolTip:hover .title {
   visibility: visible; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="hasToolTip">
    <span class="title">16753r2364</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div style='text-align:center'>
  <div class="hasToolTip">
    <span class="title">16753r2364</span>
  </div>
      
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/zonopukeku/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply a `transform` such as `transform: translateX(-50%)`. In transforms the % is of the element itself, instead of the parent as you might expect.

Comment: It is not working for me. Can u change in link please